# Send JSON data via POST PHP instead of Ajax version

Tags: php, json, ajax, curl

I have to create a JSON object that is the equivalent of a JSON object created with this Ajax code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
    type    : "POST",
    url     : "?",
    dataType: "json",
    data    : "username=" + encodeURIComponent($('input[name="username"]').val()) + "&password=" + encodeURIComponent($('input[name="password"]').val()) + "&antiForgeryToken=d98188e0f56bafa75180591e38d189ee",
    success : function(json) {
        if(json.status == 'success') {
            window.parent.location.href = json.returnUrl;
            window.parent.$.fancybox.close();
        } else {
            $('#slfErrorAlert').show();
            $('.spispinner').hide();
            $maindiv.removeAttr("disabled");
            $maindiv.removeClass("instaclass31");
        }
    }
});
});
```

I can only use PHP, and this is what I produced so far, using the `SimpleBrowser` library from [SimpleTest](http://simpletest.org/en/web_tester_documentation.html):

```
$browser = new SimpleBrowser();
$str = '?username=aaa&password=bbb&antiForgeryToken=d98188e0f56bafa75180591e38d189ee';
$json = json_encode($str);
$browser->post($httpsPage, $json);
```

I specify that I don't have to use necessarily this library and its methods, but for example I know that this can also be done using `cURL`, although I don't know how.
When I launch the script, I get as output a generic `{"status":"error"}` from the POST server I think.
What have I been missing?

*Correct syntax using `json_encode` according to @Andy: (still same error message):*

```
$data = array('username' => 'aaa', 'password' => 'bbb');
$json = json_encode($data);
```

Comment: What does the receiving script expect? Values in `$_POST` of values in `php://input` ?

Comment: @Andy I didnt't write it, but I think it receives all type of requests because in the html source code button is not type="submit"

Answer (score 0):

According to the `PHP` documentation page of `json_encode` you have to bypass an array into this method. More details you can find here: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)

In your case you probably need to build something like this:

```
$reqData = array('user' => 'foo', 'eamil' => 'bar@baz');
// {"user":"foo","email":"bar@baz"}
json_encode($reData);
```

Comment: I still get that error message '{"status":"error"}'

Comment: Can you try just this one: `$browser->post($httpsPage, $data);`

Comment: I tried your JS in Chrome and inspected request. This is what I found: https://image.prntscr.com/image/8YWdLzBBSP6Eo4MpAvD6gQ.png

Comment: Looks like content-type must be `content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: so what is it supposed to mean..?

Comment: I think it means that the request does not support json data type because JS snipped is exactly as on the screenshot. You probably need to use another approach to test your form your unit test. Also you can check your `MockConfiguration` for mocked response.

Answer (score 0):

Try with curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $httpsPage);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username='.rawurlencode('aaa').'&password='.rawurlencode('bbb').'&antiForgeryToken=d98188e0f56bafa75180591e38d189ee');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$server_output = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch);
print_r($server_output);
```

Or try with your code without encoding to json the post vars:

```
$browser = new SimpleBrowser();
$str = '?username='.rawurlencode('aaa').'&password='.rawurlencode('bbb').'&antiForgeryToken=d98188e0f56bafa75180591e38d189ee';
$browser->post($httpsPage, $str);
```

The response is going to be in json format, but the post vars I don't think they should be. From [jQuery .ajax help](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/): dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)) The type of data that you're expecting back from the server.

Comment: But then as JSON, not query formatted. And probably with a `Content-type` header, who knows.

Comment: Where do I have to put the page address here?

Comment: In the jQuery example I understand that the post data is not a json, the respose will be a json but not the post vars.

Comment: I've updated the code after noticing you have the $httpsPage var defined in your code.

Comment: Uhmm.. no json object as parameter? I don't know ajax, but as I read "dataType=json" I assumed that. However, I already tried that solution but it still doesn't work. What do you mean by "urlencode" in short?

Comment: dataType (default: Intelligent Guess (xml, json, script, or html)): The type of data that you're expecting back from the server

Comment: I update the code doing the urlencode of the username and password. Although for this example there was no need to encode them but for other values there is.

Comment: ok, got what urlencode is used for, but that wasn't the mistake. back to dataType, that ajax snippet is from the server, so why should the client expect a json object? no solution worked so far, a part of curl, which I still have to try.

Comment: If you are doing the call you are working as a client, not the server. The server will make the answer, you should not encode to json the post vars if you want to do the same that jquery code does

Comment: still that useless message error.. going to try out that curl snippet tomorrow, since here it's quite late.